How to generate Multiple Responses for single prompt with Google Gemini API?
Context
I am using google gemini-api. 
Using their Python SDK
Goal
I am trying to generate multiple possible responses for a single prompt according to the docs and API-reference
Expected result - multiple response for a single prompt 
Actual result - single response
Code I have tried
# ... more code above
model = genai.GenerativeModel(model_name="gemini-1.5-pro-latest", system_instruction=system_instruction)

response = model.generate_content("What is the meaning of life?")
resps = response.candidates


resps is a list which should contain more than 1 response. But there is only 1 response inside it.
The prompt used here is a demo prompt. But the outcome is same for any input string.

If any more information is needed please ask in the comments.

When I saw the official document GenerationConfig of Method: models.generateContent, it says as follows.

candidateCount: integer
Optional. Number of generated responses to return.
Currently, this value can only be set to 1. If unset, this will default to 1.

It seems that in the current stage, candidateCount is only 1. This is the same with "v1". Ref
But, when I saw google.ai.generativelanguage.GenerationConfig of the official document, it says as follows.

candidate_count: int
Optional. Number of generated responses to return.
This value must be between [1, 8], inclusive. If unset, this will default to 1.

From this, it seems that it is possible to try to change the value of candidate_count by the script. From this document, when your script is modified, it becomes as follows.
model = genai.GenerativeModel(
    model_name="gemini-1.5-pro-latest",
    system_instruction=system_instruction,
    generation_config=glm.GenerationConfig(candidate_count=2),
)

response = model.generate_content("What is the meaning of life?")
resps = response.candidates


In this case, please add import google.ai.generativelanguage as glm.
When I tested the above script with candidate_count=2, an error like Only one candidate can be specified occurred. I guess that this value might be able to be changed in the future update. When a value of more than 1 got to be able to be used, please test the above-modified script.

References:

GenerationConfig
google.ai.generativelanguage.GenerationConfig


I ran your code. I am getting the error BadRequest: Only one candidate can be specified too

@Curious Learner Thank you for replying. About I ran your code. I am getting the error BadRequest: Only one candidate can be specified too, I got the same response. From this response and the official document, I guessed that in the current stage, only value 1 can be used to candidateCount. I would like to believe that this will be resolved in the future update.
